# ListView setOnItemClickListener Not Responding

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using a drawer layout that has a ListView and RelativeLayout inside it for a hamburger menu on my app. When an item on the ListView is clicked I want to change to a new activity. However when I click an item on the ListView nothing is happening. My code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="b.calvin.com.dirtymoney.MainActivity"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hourlyRate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enterHourlyRate"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Hourly Rate:"
    android:id="@+id/enterHourlyRate"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Make It Rain"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hourlyRate"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/start"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hourlyRate"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hourlyRate"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/start"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:id="@+id/confirmHourlyRate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hourlyRate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<Chronometer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_above="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="$$ Money"
    android:id="@+id/money"
    android:layout_below="@+id/start"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/stop" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Edit"
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hourlyRate"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/confirmHourlyRate"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/confirmHourlyRate"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Day: $"
    android:id="@+id/dayText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edit" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Week: $"
    android:id="@+id/weekText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dayText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dayText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dayText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Month: $"
    android:id="@+id/monthText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/weekText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weekText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/weekText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Year: $"
    android:id="@+id/yearText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/monthText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/monthText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/monthText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total: $"
    android:id="@+id/totalText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yearText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yearText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/yearText"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/dayMoney"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dayText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dayText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dayText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/weekMoney"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weekText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/weekText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weekText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/monthMoney"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/monthText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/monthText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/monthText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/yearMoney"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yearText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yearText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yearText"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/totalMoney"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/totalText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/totalText"/>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "BroadcastTest";
private Intent intent;

private Button start;
private Button stop;
private Button confirmRate;
private Button edit;
private EditText hourlyRate;
private TextView money;
private TextView dayMoney;
private TextView weekMoney;
private TextView monthMoney;
private TextView yearMoney;
private TextView totalMoney;
private double moneyEarned;
private double secondsRate;
private double hrlyRate;
private double currentDayMoney;
private double currentWeekMoney;
private double currentMonthMoney;
private double currentYearMoney;
private double currentTotalMoney;
private String savedDayMoney;
private String savedWeekMoney;
private String savedMonthMoney;
private String savedYearMoney;
private String savedTotalMoney;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private String mActivityTitle;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    confirmRate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmHourlyRate);
    edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    hourlyRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourlyRate);
    money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money);
    dayMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dayMoney);
    weekMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weekMoney);
    monthMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthMoney);
    yearMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearMoney);
    totalMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalMoney);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    }

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "New Shift", "Poop Slips", "Statistics", "Help"};
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to test custom string on Toast ?  Example: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Testing List item click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan yes it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after `addDrawerItems();`

```
mDrawerList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
mDrawerList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
mDrawerList.bringToFront();
mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
```

to

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
```

Answer (score 0):

i can not see any statement for starting a new activity in your `OnItemClick` method. You are just getting a `string` and making a `Toast` on the same activity. try to get the `id` of `Item` being clicked and start an `Activity` on the basis of that `id`.

here is a little code for you.

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, parent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if this code make your app running. and mark this answer accepted.